# which python and tensorflow version is used to train DeepLab v3+ using tensorflow api?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, object-detection-api, deeplab

I have been getting multiple errors which are due to conflicts in the TensorFlow version installed in my system and the version used to write the code in Tensorflow API.
I am using python 3.6.7 and Tensorflow 2.0 to get started with the code https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/deeplab/g3doc/installation.md

But I am getting several errors :

1. flags = tf.app.flags
   AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'app. 
   As I am using 2.0 , I replaced tf.app.flags with tf.compat.v1.flags.
2. from tensorflow.contrib import slim as contrib_slim
   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.contrib'

I am not able to solve the second one.
Can I get help to know which python and tensorflow version should be used to run DeepLab v3+?

Comment: Since the code could not find the `tf.contrib` module, I think you should try running the code with TF 1.x versions. `tf.contrib` is deprecated in TF 2.0.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the Tensorflow version 1.x to run the DeepLabV3+ model because it uses a session to run and also the slim library which is based on the TensorFlow 1.x. And so your two problems can be solved as:

1. Do not need to replace tf.app.flags with tf.compat.v1.flags.
2. To run DeepLabV3+ model, you need to put deeplab and slim folder in a folder (deeplab_slim), 
   and export them by running following export commands from this parent folder (deeplab_slim):

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:`pwd`:`pwd`/slim
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:`pwd`:`pwd`/deeplab
```